# hosting: how to rewrite path to parent directory index.html

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I have a URL structure with the following pattern, which are just aliases of each other.

- example.com/products/sku/index.html
- example.com/product/sku/product-slug/index.html

However, I wouldn't like to upload the same index.html file twice for accomplishing this when hosting under firebase.

I have tried to add the following to `firebase.json` without luck

```json
{
  "hosting": {
    "rewrites": [
      { "source": "/products/*/*", "destination": "../index.html"}
    ]
  }
}
```

Which would basically just take a request to  `example.com/product/sku/product-slug/index.html` and render as  `example.com/product/sku/index.html`, however that doesn't seem to work as the relative file seems to not be found.

Ideally something like this would be ideal:

```json
{ "source": "/products/:sku/**", "destination": "/products/:sku/index.html"}
```

Is there any way to achieve this kind of behaviour on firebase hosting?

Comment: Any chance you found a solution to this? I'm having similar problems. I know that rewrites can't use for example the /:sku but it doesn't seem to work on redirects either, as some have suggested.

Comment: I ended up going with redirects instead. Globs seems to work over there: `      { "source": "/p/:sku/**", "destination": "/p/:sku", "type": 302 }`.  I hope that helps.

Comment: For some reason globs didn't work for me on redirects.. I ended up using regex (Google's RE2) that actually do work. Thank you, though!